# Using variables in C brand new to the program

Tags: c

okay so im trying to ask user to an input of a number and then assign that number to variable this is not happening with this obviously.I also want it to then print the variable made. Please explain when the variable is assigned and where the number goes when im asking for it.

Coming from python so don't know what else to do but ask it this way

```
h=raw_input('please enter number')
print h
```

I want to do that in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int this_is_a_number;

    printf( "Please enter a number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &this_is_a_number );
    printf( "You entered %d", this_is_a_number );
    a=%d
    printf(a)
    return 0;

}
```

Why is this one not working I thought it addressed the problems
    #include

```
int main()
{
    int this_is_a_number;
    int a;

    printf( "Please enter a number: /n" );
    scanf( "%d", &this_is_a_number );
    printf( "You entered %d", this_is_a_number );
    a=this_is_a_number
    printf("%d/n",&a)

    return 0;

}
```

Here are errors for most recent code:

```
Building m.obj.
C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive\firstCShit\m.c(4): warning #2117: Old-style function definition for 'main'.
C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive\firstCShit\m.c(12): error #2001: Syntax error: expected ';' but found 'printf'.
C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive\firstCShit\m.c(14): warning #2234: Argument 2 to 'printf' does not match the format string; expected 'int' but found 'int *'.
C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive\firstCShit\m.c(14): error #2001: Syntax error: expected ';' but found 'return'.
*** Error code: 1 ***
Done.
```

Comment: "this is not happening" what is happening exactly?

Comment: Are you asking about `a=%d`? Because that should throw a compiler error.

Comment: do you mean `int a = this_is_a_number; printf("%d\n", a);`?

Comment: I just relooked atit and realized the variable is this_is_a_number what does the %d do and where did the number i inputed go and how do i print a variable

Comment: You already printed a variable with the line `printf( "You entered %d", this_is_a_number );`

Comment: maybe you want to check [printf manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)?

Comment: Firstly, you haven't declared 'a' and secondly you cannot store variable  name in another variable. To do that you might need some complex programs with string type variables.

Comment: It says print please enter a number but how does it know that it should wait for input.

Comment: @user3026468 that's what `scanf` does

Comment: okay understanding things more. Is it just me or can you assign a variable to variable in Python? like lets say a had a value of 5 and b had a value of 4. Could c=a+b? you can't do something like this in C

Comment: @user3026468 the syntax is identical. you just need to *declare* the variable before you use it: C needs to know to reserve space for it on the stack

Comment: thanks off topic but if you feel like answering itd be helpful. After I learn C I want to go to Objective C, thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

1. You have not declared variable `a`
   Declare it along with this_is_a_number like `int this_is_a_number, a;`
2. Your assignment statement is wrong
   Use `a = this_is_a_number;`
3. printf needs a format specifier.
   `printf("%d", a);`

Answer (score 1):

A line by line breakdown of your attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Reserve the space in which to store the number
    int this_is_a_number;

    // Output a string, note no newline (\n) at the end of 
    // the string means this will probably not be printed 
    // before moving to the next statement
    printf( "Please enter a number: " );

    //read in an integer (%d) and store it at the address of the variable (this_is_a_number)
    scanf( "%d", &this_is_a_number );

    // Print the number entered, again no newline, but stdout should be flushed 
    printf( "You entered %d", this_is_a_number );

    // This line is syntactically incorrect and makes no sense
    a=%d

    // This line is semantically incorrect, probably a type error
    // printf requires a format string, like in the example two lines up
    printf(a)

    // Exit successfully
    return 0;

}
```

To address your edit, the equivalent C is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int h;
    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &h);
    printf("%d\n", h);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this no working either?

Comment: @user3026468 *what* is not working?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     int this_is_a_number;
  int a;

     printf( "Please enter a number: /n" );
     scanf( "%d", &this_is_a_number );
     printf( "You entered %d", this_is_a_number );
     a=this_is_a_number
  printf("%d/n",&a)
  
     return 0;

 }

Comment: @user3026468 what is not working with that code?

Comment: I put it above, its saying many errors ill post them

Comment: @user3026468 read the error messages, they tell you exactly what is wrong. All statements in C must end with a ';'

Comment: added those(python problems) still having trouble it adds many numbers on to the number i entered

Comment: @user3026468 `\n` is not the same as `/n`.

Comment: I took out both of those actually

Comment: Building m.obj.
C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive\firstCShit\m.c(4): warning #2117: Old-style function definition for 'main'.
C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive\firstCShit\m.c(12): warning #2234: Argument 2 to 'printf' does not match the format string; expected 'int' but found 'int *'.
Building m.exe.
Done.

Comment: @user3026468 ah, you are printing `&a` which is the address of `a` not the value stored in `a`. Lose the `&`.

Comment: @user3026468 if this answered you're question, click the tick next to the post to mark the answer as "accepted"